# Does Mathematica support out-of-core Associations?

Tags: memory, data-structures, associations

I often find myself collecting data in an `Association[]` which outgrows my computer's main memory. Does *Mathematica* support any out-of-core equivalent?

Ideally, I would like to have a solution that uses similar syntax to `Association`s, with support for arbitrary *Mathematica* expressions as keys and values.

Comment: If your data storage requirements are large then why not connect to a database?

Comment: It does not yet, but the support for it mau be added in the future (I am not speaking in any official capacity here, so this is just a guess).

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I am not very familiar with *Mathematica*'s database capabilities, but from what I've seen, the `DatabaseLink` package only works with SQL databases, restricting me to SQL data types. I need to have a database that works with arbitrary *Mathematica* expressions.

Comment: @DavidZhang Can you give an example what you mean by arbitrary Mathematica Expressions?   There is nothing stopping you from storing a Mathematica expression or an association as a text string in a database field or fields, for evaluation (or not) on reading.

Comment: I've used MongoDB which is NoSQL. See Q&A on this site.